# Save ListView data and get it back on application start

Tags: java, android, xml, caching, android-listview

I have a simple application with one activity containing listview in which data is loaded with a custom adapter and some json content fetched in an asynctask, minified code below

Main.class

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
class load_data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
   // parse some JSON data and store it in " String[] var,var2,var3 " variable.....
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
final Listadapter adapter = new    
Listadapter(Main.this,var1,var2,var3);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
//rest of the code
```

Listadapter.class

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         // put values into textviews of the listview row
         return convertView;
   }
```

The above listView implementation works perfectly, but the listview is loaded every time the application is started How do I change the code so that the listview shows to me the old retained data and then load new data and refresh the listview.

the concept is similar to the android twitter app where the older tweets are shown and new tweets are loaded above the older one upon application restart.

Comment: This could depend on the nature of the data you are populating the ListView with. If the content to be loaded is highly volatile, it's better to load it `onCreate()`, else if the content is relatively non-volatile and new data gets appended everytime, then it's apt to use a file based cache as specified by @Gleb.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read this article: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In your case, I think the easiest way is to save list data during run time to some cache file (simple text file would do) and then load the data from it during `onCreate()` of your activity. This way you could always load the data from your cache file even if your application was killed. After loading list data from file you could start your `AsyncTask`, load data from web and then reload the list at `onPostExecute()`.